# Error: `getwd` : No such file or directory - getcwd?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Can you anyone help me how to solve this problem

> gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:71:in `getwd':
>   No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: Maybe the current working directory of the shell that's used to start the Rails app doesn't exist (maybe removed by another process), and therefore getcwd throws an error.